# Symfony Twig: "Defining the initRuntime() method in the "form" extension is deprecated"

Tags: symfony, twig, deprecated

After updating everything in my Symfony project by command:

```
composer update
```

I have one information about use of deprecated method in my profiler. Thats how it's looking:

> DEPRECATED - Defining the initRuntime() method in the "form" extension is deprecated. Use the `needs_environment` option to get the Twig_Environment instance in filters, functions, or tests; or explicitly implement Twig_Extension_InitRuntimeInterface if needed (not recommended).  -
>   Called from Twig_Environment::initRuntime() at line 408
>   Called from Twig_Environment::loadTemplate() at line 126
>   Called from TwigEngine::load() at line 50
>   Called from TwigEngine::render() at line 67
>   Called from TwigEngine::render() at line 50
>   Called from TimedTwigEngine::render() at line 92
>   Called from TwigEngine::renderResponse() at line 176
>   Called from Controller::render() at line 35
>   Called from SecurityController::loginAction()
>   Called from call_user_func_array() at line 3054
>   Called from HttpKernel::handleRaw() at line 3016
>   Called from HttpKernel::handle() at line 3165
>   Called from ContainerAwareHttpKernel::handle() at line 2406
>   Called from Kernel::handle() at line 28

I tried to found the file which generates this message. This is in
**./vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php**

And the line is:

```
    (407) if (!$this->runtimeInitialized) {
    (408)     $this->initRuntime();
    (409) }
```

And I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#environment-aware-filters

Comment: Symfony is not yet 100% compatible with Twig 2. This means that the latest Twig version trigger some deprecation warnings. Deprecation warnings don't hurt anybody and it's save to ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this may have been a bug, and has been fixed in code. You will probably have to wait for the next release, but it's likely safe to ignore until then:
https://github.com/bolt/bolt/issues/4450